# CommandButton action не работае с Spring Security

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, primefaces

Уменя проблема с кнопкой в форме Primefaces CommandButton. Когда подключаю Spring Security, то action перестает работать, т.е. метод бина не вызывается. Без Spring Security этот же код работает без проблем. Не могу понять почему. Помогите?

Я использую Primefaces 5.2. и Spring Security 4.0.2.

У меня есть бин

```
@Getter
@Setter
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class LoginController implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private String userName = "admin";
private String password = "123";

public void doLogin() {
System.out.println("test"); 
} 
}
```

И login страница с кнопкой

```
<p:commandButton value="Войти в систему" action="#{loginController.doLogin()}" />
```

Вот конфик Spring Security

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SpringSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
      auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("admin").password("123").roles("USER");
}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

У вас конфигуратор не дописан.

Надо еще в `SpringSecurityConfiguration` добавить и настроить под себя

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http.authorizeRequests()
    .antMatchers("/admin/**").access("hasRole('ROLE_USER')")
    .and()
        .formLogin().loginPage("/login").failureUrl("/login?error")
        .usernameParameter("username").passwordParameter("password")        
    .and()
        .logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/login?logout")
    .and()
        .csrf();        
}
```

Comment: Он у меня прописан. Не указал его в начале. http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/javax.faces.resource/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login.xhtml")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
                .logout()
                .permitAll(); Но это не решает проблему.